# asyncData valores

Tags: javascript, vue.js, web, vscode, async

Estoy teniendo problemas con asyncData, lo estoy utilizando en el script de vue. Necesito retornar una serie de objetos guardados dentro de mi base. Para ello utilizo:

```
async asyncData({params}) {
  const cars = await axios.get('http://localhost:4050/api/getCars/${page.id}/${params.id}');
  return {car: cars.data}
},
```

He probado con `$axios` pero ni esta ni la otra funcionan. No posee errores, todo compila correctamente pero no muestra los datos en pantalla. La ruta que se utiliza es la siguiente:

```
/getCars/:page/:name?/:large?
```

Necesito obtener el `name` de estos, pero no sé cómo. Lo que hago es escribir dentro del template

```
<b-col v-for="car in car" :key="car.index">
<h1>{{car.name}}</h1>
</b-col>
```

Comment: Por lo que veo está bien, ¿qué te sale cuando haces log de `cars`?

Comment: Tenés mal las comillas en la url `'http://localhost:4050/api/getCars/${page.id}/${params.id}'`, para incrustar variables tendrías que usar [comillas invertidas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Además te conviene hacer un `try/catch` para manejar posibles errores en la llamada ajax

Comment: tienes varios errores bor, primero de donde viene el page? segundo no estas usando literal templates